# Error '80004005' MySQL Connection

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, odbc

been attempting to find an answer to this for a while now, to no success, so I'm hoping someone on here may have an idea what's causing this.

Basically, I'm setting up a new website, IIS7, ASP driven, with a MySQL database. This is a new virtual server, so it's a fresh install of pretty much everything.

MySQL server's on, users set up, showing up fine in NaviCat. ODBC connector's installed, I'm using this connection string:

```
MM_dsnTest_STRING = "Provider=MSDASQL;driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=localhost;uid=[my UID here];pwd=[my password here];database=[my database here];option=3;"
```

Which works on the other, functionally identical site I have running.

And yet, upon testing the DB from ASP code, I get this:

```
error '80004005'
/dbtest.asp, line 9
```

That line is

```
rsCheck_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_dsnTest_STRING
```

Some googling around for this, and most of the suggestions were along the lines of "Install the ODBC driver" which I have already done, "Install the Net Connector" which I have tried and didn't solve anything, and one suggestion that it might be I might need to set the App Pool to allow 32bit applications in order to make Classic ASP work (but that was already switched on).

Everything else has been about connecting to Access databases.

So I'm at a loss. Any insights?

Comment: @AaronMiller Seems [MSDN shows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676107(v=vs.85).aspx) you can pass either a string or an active connection object: Sets or returns a String value that contains a definition for a connection if the connection is closed, or a Variant containing the current Connection object if the connection is open. Default is a null object reference. See the ConnectionString property.

Comment: @AaronMiller a little less snark might also be helpful.

Comment: Some additional information could help... Is that the sum total of the error message you get? Are other pages able to connect to the database or is it just this one? Are you sure MySQL was set up identically on the new server?

Comment: What happens if you lose the "Provider=MSDASQL;" bit of your connection string?